# Get all matched groups PREG PHP flavor

Tags: php, regex

Pattern : `'/x(?: (\d))+/i'`

String : `x 1 2 3 4 5`

Returned : `1 Match Position[11-13] '5'`

I want to catch all possible repetitions, or does it return 1 result per group?

I want the following :

Desired Output:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [4-5]   `1`
2.  [6-7]   `2`
3.  [8-9]   `3`
4.  [10-11] `4`
5.  [12-13] `5`
```

Which I was able to achieve just by copy pasting the group, but this is not what I  want. I want a **dynamic group capturing**

Pattern: `x(?: (\d))(?: (\d))(?: (\d))(?: (\d))(?: (\d))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use one group to capture multiple texts and then access them with PCRE. Instead, you can either match the whole substring with `\d+(?:\s+\d+)*` and then split with space:

```
$re2 = '~\d+(?:\s+\d+)*~';
if (preg_match($re2, $str, $match2)) {
    print_r(preg_split("/\\s+/", $match2[0]));
}
```

Alternatively, use a `\G` based regex to return multiple *matches*:

```
(?:x|(?!^)\G)\s*\K\d+
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/dY9iD6/2)

Here is a [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/38OSAU):

```
$str = "x 1 2 3 4 5"; 
$re1 = '~(?:x|(?!^)\G)\s*\K\d+~'; 
preg_match_all($re1, $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Here, `(?:x|(?!^)\G)` is acting as a leading boundary (match the whitespaces and digits only after `x` or each successful match). When the digits are encountered, all the characters matched so far are omitted with the `\K` operator.

Comment: What about matching tags example   keyword </a><p>test</p><h1></h1><a></a>    I need to grab all tags about 2-3 tags deep.

Comment: That is a different question, and to solve that you will need a DOM parser.

Comment: Yes, I have simpledom, But the files are mixed with PHP. This is the project. I just need to detect next 2-4 tags

Comment: I do not understand what output you need for that string of tags.

Comment: Example something like this '/test(?=(</?(?'needthistag'\w+))[^>]){3)/'  on the sample code from my first comment I would grab </p> <h1> </h1>

Comment: Still it is not clear. Try [`(?:\btest(?=<)|(?!^)\G)\s*<\/?([^<>]+)>(?![^<>]*<\/a)`](https://regex101.com/r/rP4vL8/3) or [`(?:\btest(?=<)|(?!^)\G)\s*<\/?([^<>]+)>`](https://regex101.com/r/rP4vL8/2) to get all after `test`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101805/discussion-between-c3cris-and-wiktor-stribizew).